# Warning: file_put_contents(localhost/video/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Yoyo\download.php

Tags: php, http, file-upload, upload, file-put-contents

I'm implmenting a YouTube downloader which stores video onto a server from [here](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader). I've modified the code for the downloading YouTube video on a server rather than a computer. Here is my code for download.php:

```
include_once('config.php');
 // Check download token
if (empty($_GET['mime']) OR empty($_GET['token']))
{
  exit('Invalid download token 8{');
}

// Set operation params
$mime = filter_var($_GET['mime']);
$ext  = str_replace(array('/', 'x-'), '', strstr($mime, '/'));
$url  = base64_decode(filter_var($_GET['token']));
$name = urldecode($_GET['title']). '.' .$ext; 

// Fetch and serve
if ($url)
{
  $size=get_size($url);
  $file_path ="localhost/video/";
  $download_video_file = file_put_contents($file_path, fopen($url, 'r'));
  exit;
}

// Not found
exit('File not found 8{');
```

It gives me an error(warning)

```
Warning: file_put_contents(localhost/video/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Yoyo\download.php on line 43
```

I verify that there is localhost/video exists. I've also removed  localhost:

```
   $file_path ="/video/";
```

and checked it, but it is still throwing the same warning. What is the problem?

Comment: You do understand that `localhost` and `http://localhost` are a different thing?

Comment: Yes, but you cant write http://localhost  it gives 

failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connection

Comment: Please clarify the question and code sample and don't post commented out code that is not needed to solve the problem. But mainly, you're trying to write data into a directory, not into a file.

Comment: You're trying to write into an empty file name? Also, does the `localhost/video` directory exist?

Comment: You cannot write to `http://localhost/...` (with or without http://), you cannot write to *any* HTTP URL! You want to write to a normal **local folder**, like `C:\foo\bar\baz\video` instead.

Comment: Formatted source code. Removed commented out source code. Fixed grammar and spelling.